# Router-view not load second component

Tags: vue.js

The redirect to new link and styles css works, but no method or event inicialize on the new component.
The component navbar keep going perfectly and the inspector not display no error. If reload page, all works again. Apologize my english

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Routes from './routes'
import App from './componentes/App.vue'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: Routes,
    // mode: 'history'`Texto preformateado`
});

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <encabezado></encabezado>
    <!-- <keep-alive> -->
        <router-view></router-view>
    <!-- </keep-alive> -->
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import encabezado from './encabezado.vue'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    encabezado
  }, 
}
</script>
```

**route.js**

```
import Financiero from './componentes/vistas/financiero.vue';
import Principal from './componentes/principal/principal.vue';
export default [
  {
    path: '/financiero',
    component: Financiero,
    name: 'Financiero'
  },
  { path: '/principal', component: Principal, name: 'principal' },
]
```

**component**

```
<template>
  <div :class="{dvContainer:movil}">
      <div v-if="movil" class="fixed-action-btn">
        <a class="btn-floating btn-large sidenav-trigger pulse waves-effect waves-light purple darken-3" href="#" data-target="slide-out">
          <i class="large material-icons">chat</i>
        </a>
      </div>
    <ul id="slide-out" class="collapsible" :class="{sidenav: movil, enCelularSide: movil, menuLateral: !movil }" style="padding-bottom: 30px !important;">
      <li class="active">
        <div class="collapsible-header" ><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>Analisar proyecto</div>
        <div class="collapsible-body cuerpoItemColapse">
          <mapa></mapa>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import evaluacion from '../navegacion/evaluacion.vue'
import mapa from '../navegacion/mapa.vue'
import resumen from '../navegacion/resumen.vue'
export default{
```

Comment: Can you try to import your component with a `@` for example: `import Financiero from '@/componentes/vistas/financiero.vue';`
`import Principal from ' @/componentes/principal/principal.vue';` Let me know how it goes please...

Comment: The same. If refresh page, all works again. I'll create a new proyecto to do test wit vueRouter.

ERROR in ./src/routes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/componentes/vistas/financiero.vue' in '/home/mauro/Online/explorador/src'
 @ ./src/routes.js 1:0-61
 @ ./src/main.js

Comment: Please, refer to my answer down to see a sandbox example I'm working on and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Financiero from '@/componentes/vistas/financiero.vue';
import Principal from ' @/componentes/principal/principal.vue';
```

[Example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/llx6yqr9ll)